# Exclude stylesheet

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For an application I'm developping, I want to build in the functionality to generate an invoice. This invoice is configurable, and I want to show a preview in my page. Based on the data I send back to my C# back-end, I will generate a .PDF file which will be made available for downloading.

In the back-end generation process, I will have no access to my stylesheet and will have to define all my classes completely inline. Because I want my preview to truly match what the invoice will end up looking like, I need to be able to exclude all other styling from the preview element.

Is there a way to do this?

Example:

```
<link href="Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
    <p>Use classes defined in style.css</p>

    <div EXCLUDE CSS OUTSIDE THIS SCOPE>
        <p>No access to style.css</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I understand that I could achieve the desired effect by simply making sure the previewer is placed outside of the scope where I inject my CSS, but due to the structure of my project, this is not an option.

Extra info:

I'm using a stylesheet purchased by the company I'm doing this project for. The stylesheet is very poorly set-up, however, and includes all sorts of default styling like:

```
table {
    color: black !important;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to exclude all that styling without having to individually overwrite every property set in that stylesheet.

Comment: You could use an ID before all your selectors. That way it will only display on the elements which parent has an ID of whatever.

Comment: That would work if I wanted to define styles that only work within the new section. I'm looking to EXCLUDE classes from the outer section. Also, using an ID just for CSS class selection is a pretty bad practice, since IDs are used for all kinds of things, not just CSS.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, you want the css owrking outside your DIV but being completly not effective inside the <div EXCLUDE CSS OUTSIDE THIS SCOPE> right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: You'll have one ID to select. You wont have ID's on all elements. Sorry if blunt, but do you understand how CSS works?

Comment: I understand what you are telling me, but my actual problem is way more advance than the code shown above. It's intended as an example. In my full code, I would have to assign IDs to a lot of different elements or overwrite externally defined properties, both of which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the `all` property, and the `initial` value to reset a property to the default settings of the browser. So if you wrap the part you want to be "excluded" from your styles into a tag to which you apply a class like the following (i.e. combined with the `*` selector), it should have the effect you want:

```
.unset * {
  all: initial;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Use classes defined in style.css</p>

    <div class="unset">
        <p>No access to style.css</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But unfortunately, `all` does not yet work in IE/Edge, it's "under consideration": http://caniuse.com/#search=all

Still, if your stylesheet doesn't use too many different properties (and if you know them), you could list those, define all of them as `initial` and apply it, using a selector as shown above. Example:

```
.unset * {
  font-size: initial;
  color: initial;
  background: initial;
  text-decoration: initial;
  margin: initial;
  padding: initial;
}
```

Comment: That would only add more styling. If I'd want to remove styling set in a higher layer of the DOM, I'd have to overwrite each individual property on every element.

Comment: This looks very promising, let me try this.

Comment: Although I very much appreciate this suggestion and will definetly remember it for the future, this option is not supported in even the latest versions of IE or Edge (because ofcourse it isn't).

Comment: I could read out the complete property list from the Chrome inspector I suppose, but I think it will be a very substantial list.

Comment: well, not from Chrome, just from the stylesheet whose application you want to avoid (I don't know it, as I said, it only makes sense if there aren't too many)

Comment: I marked this as the accepted answer because it does really fix everything as specified in my question. Although it doesn't solve my problem due the need for IE11 support, I appreciate the effort.

Comment: I want to personally thank you for this answer. You saved me hours of considering using an iframe and having to maneuver its contents for style and function binding. Now i can rely on this to move forward.

Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the :not() selector and add it to each class in your CSS. Here is a simple example

```css
div p:not(.secondParagraph){font-style:italic}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p class="secondParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

For your problem you may do something like that:

Select elements with class "myClass" excluding those that are immediate children of elements with ID "myID" is:

```
*:not(#myID) > .para
```

However, the :not() selector is not supported in IE8 or less. look [here](https://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) for details about it.

Comment: This appraoch would require me to define a :not for every class in every style sheet, and would also not work with any styling defined in-line.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need apply styling of .css file in page.just add `disabled =true` attribute .so that it won't apply the styling from that file.

see the  link [stackover link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864174/chrome-disable-all-styles-from-specific-css-file) for reference.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourstyleXXX.css" disabled =true />`

Comment: If I inject this style in my header WITHOUT the disabled property, then inject it again in my preview element WITH the disabled property would that block the styling in (and only IN) my preview?

Comment: @FvB this `disabled` is work on whole Document level.  if need  Document level disable you can use this. but if u need to disable in part of document of Html then it won't work. in that case  @Johannes approach will work

Answer (score -1):

You could use ID like Gezzasa said.

```
<div id="expluded">
    <p>Something.</p>
</div>
```

In css get new class as in.

```
#expluded {

put your parameters hare.

}
```

Comment: Using IDs for CSS is a bad practice, as IDs should be unique which completely defies the basics of the CASCADING keyword in CSS.

Also, IDs are used for many purposes, not just CSS.